# How to copy/move images from array to a folder in php

Tags: php, arrays, image

I have two folders named 'avatars' and 'small_avatars'. What I am trying to do is to compare the contents of these folders (both have images) with each other using arrays, like so (see code below) but I don't think that it works. Could someone check that and point out what needs to be changed to make it work? Do I need to define the datatype of the file that I am saving in to the array?

```
   $dirBig= $root.AVATAR_DIRECTORY;
   $dirSmall= $root.SMALL_AVATAR_DIRECTORY;

   $imagesBig = array("image/gif","image/jpg","image/jpeg","image/png");
   $imagesSmall = array("image/gif","image/jpg","image/jpeg","image/png");

   // check if avatar directory exists then copy the names 
   // of the files to an array
   if (is_dir($dirBig)){
       // for debug purposes
      echo ("$dirBig on dir </br></br>");
       }else{
      echo ("dir not found\n" );
   }
   if ($isot=opendir($dirBig)){

      while ((false !== $file = readdir($isot))):
      if ($file[0] == ".")continue; {
         echo ("Filename in avatars : $file </br>");
         $imagesBig[]=$file;
      }
      endwhile;
      closedir($isot);
   }

   // check if small avatar directory exists then copy the names 
   // of the files to an array
   if (is_dir($dirSmall)) {
      echo ("</br>".SMALL_AVATAR_DIRECTORY. " on dir </br></br>");

   }else{
      echo("dir not found \n");
   }
   if ($pienet=opendir($dirSmall)) {
      while ((false !== $file = readdir($pienet))) :

      if ($file[0] == ".") continue;{

         echo ("Filename in small avatars: $file</br>");
         $imagesSmall[] = $file;
      }
      endwhile;
   closedir($pienet);
   }

//compare the two arrays with each other
$comp_result= array_diff($imagesBig, $imagesSmall);`
```

The result from comparing the two arrays with each other contains the names of the files that are **not** present in the 'small_avatar' folder. The filenames don't have extension like :".jpg,.png, etc. The next thing that I am trying to achieve is to copy those images from '$comp_result' to the 'small_avatar' folder by trying this: 
**edit** Replaced former For loop with this foreach. Now there are no errors but images are still not copied from the array to the folder... :(

```
    $a = $comp_result;
  foreach ($a as $img){

     if (move_uploaded_file($img, $dirSmall)){
        $imagetools->resizeImage($dirSmall, NULL, NULL, NULL, THREAD_AVATAR_MAX_WIDTH, THREAD_AVATAR_MAX_HEIGHT, AVATAR_KEEP_IMAGE_ASPECT_RATIO);
     }else{
         echo("Copying file ".$img." failed to dir ".$dirSmall." !</br>");

  }
  }
```

But it doesn't work. I get errormessages such as:

- Warning: copy(): Filename cannot be empty
- Warning: copy(5006): failed to open stream: File or directory doesn't exists in...
  And my array starts from [4] not [0]?? Any ideas why this happens?

I would really appreciate if someone could help me get this function to work. I've been searching through google for couple of days now.

I've tried `glob()`, but that didn't give me any values...

Thank you in advance! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't solve all the errors, but I think the first one (undefined offset) is because this line

```
(false !== $file = readdir($isot))
```

needs to be written as

```
(false !== ($file = readdir($isot)))
```

because of operator precedence.

Comment: Thanks, that solved one 'undefined offset' but not all.. Trying to figure out my problem..